# angular ssr and BreakpointObserver

Tags: angular, seo, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-ssr

I'm using BreakpointObserver to modify my view on the client side based on the size of the browser, however I believe this doesn't work on server side rendering as everything looks weird and components that should be hidden gets shown on prerender.

Is the BreakpointObserver known to work with ssr or do I need to come up with a different solution. I'm only doing ssr for the SEO results and don't really need hydration in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`BreakpointObserver` relies on `MediaMatcher`. `MediaMatcher` is noop when run outside a browser environment.

So no, `BreakpointObserver` won't fire when run server side.

Comment: what's the recommended way of being seo compliant if you're using these then? use puppeteer on a reverse proxy by routing user-agents?